# R Shiny - file upload always NULL

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm putting together a shiny app and trying something along the lines of the following:

```
require("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(fileInput(inputId = "dataFile", label = NULL)),
  fluidRow(wellPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "rawText")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    upFile <- input$dataFile

    if(!is.null(upFile)) {
      raw.dat <<- reactive({
        read.csv(file = upFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      })
    } else raw.dat <<- reactive({})
  })

  output$rawFile <- renderTable(as.data.frame(raw.dat()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and yet even after I upload a file, `raw.dat()` always, *always* returns NULL.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Why are you using `<<-` with assignment here? Where are you trying to assign this value? Why isn't it just a reactive value in the server block itself? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that we can actually run to test and verify possible solutions. Important parts of the code are missing here.

Comment: possibly unrelated, but I've experienced issues with uploading files while viewing the Shiny app in RStudio. Opening the app in a web browser resolved the issue.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I thought this was reproducible enough; I'll put together a filler app with just this code. I'm using the `<<-` so that the raw.dat reactive would be assigned in the environment outside the observer, or is that unnecessary?
@Adrian FWIW, I've been using Firefox to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `raw.dat` object reactive. Because it's dependent on `input$dataFile` it will do the observing for you.

```
raw.dat <- reactive({
  upFile <- input$dataFile
  if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
  read.csv(upFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: I figured out the problem... I hadn't upped the max file size option (`options(shiny.maxRequestSize = fileSizeInMB*1024^2)`) and the files I was testing with were bigger than the 5MB default. Oops, that's embarassing. I actually previously had something remarkably similar to what you put (but was trying the `observe` in a vain attempt to fix it), so I'll accept your answer--thanks for the help! Your method is definitely more elegant than the one in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded file is likely larger than the default size allowed, change the acceptable value using:

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = MB*1024^2) #Change MB to suit your needs
```